# Remove DOCTYPE and its containing tags from xml using XmlOptions

Tags: java, xml, security, parsing, fortify

I have below request and i want to remove DOCTYPE and its contaning ENTITY tag(s) . i dont have parser access but in class i can pass XMlOptions so is there any way that i can remove DOCTYPE using XMLOptions , so XMl enity expansion vunerbility will removed

request i am using to send

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ENTITY xeebri2n0 "o16ja">
<!ENTITY xeebri2n1 "&xeebri2n0;&xeebri2n0;">
<!ENTITY xeebri2n2 "&xeebri2n1;&xeebri2n1;">
<!ENTITY xeebri2n3 "&xeebri2n2;&xeebri2n2;">]>
<SubmitPaymentRequest xmlns="http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema" xmlns:bim="http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema/BIM">
    <EPWFHeaderInfo>
        <RequestId>IR1BCSRDQBSIRW7745 &xeebri2n3;<RequestId>
        <SendTimeStamp>2019-12-23T14:23:01.183-05:00<SendTimeStamp>
        <MessageSrcSystem>IPS<MessageSrcSystem>
    </EPWFHeaderInfo>
</SubmitPaymentRequest>
```

EPWFSubmitPaymentEventHandler.java class where i am using above class to parse

```
EPWFSubmitPaymentEventHandler{
public String handleEventMessage(String inXml, XmlObject xmlBean, Map<String, String> metaInfo) {


SubmitPaymentRequestWrapper request = new SubmitPaymentRequestWrapper(inXml);

}
}
```

class where i am parsing the xml.

```
  SubmitPaymentRequestWrapper {

    public SubmitPaymentRequestWrapper(String reqXml, XmlOptions options) throws XmlException {
            this(SubmitPaymentRequestDocument.Factory.parse(reqXml, options));
        }
}
```

in Above SubmitPaymentRequestWrapper.java class i can not access SubmitPaymentRequestDocument.java So,
is there any way that i can disbale or remove the DOCTYPE using passing XMLOptions ?

Answer (score 1):

We usually don't remove the doctype elements manually, but parametrise the the parser to ignore it. How you can do that depends unfortunately strong on which parser it is. In JAXB you can do it like this:

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
// xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("test.xml"));
```

The line with `XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD` will disable the doctype completely. If I recall it correctly all entities defined will be replaced with empty strings then (don't take my word - test it).

The line with `XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES` is there, because I have found out, that XML parsers in Java's default configuration are not vulnerable to XML bomb attacks (like the one you have in the XML). The attack will stop after 60k iterations quite fast (remember - don't take my word). So after a lot of testing I decided to stop only external entities, which are a nuisance and an insecure default in Java.

If you don't use JAXB but JDOM, then external entity prevention will look differently:

```
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
File xmlFile = new File("test.xml");
builder.setExpandEntities(false);
Document document = builder.build(xmlFile);
```

It's different in Dom4J too:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
Document document = reader.read("test.xml");
```

Comment: thnx for answer but i am not using any of these i dont have permission to change  in SAXBuilder or JAXB

Comment: and still value of entity is epended in <RequestId> tag when i use SAXReader

Comment: Yes. The string disables only external entities, not the whole doctype.

Comment: Unfortunately with Dom4J disallowing the doctype will throw an exception: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#disallow-doctype-decl

Comment: so i need to prevent xml attack thats why i want to use that feature is there any way that i can remove whole DOCTYPE and processed the data without doctype instead throwing an exception

Comment: The question is: which attack are you trying to prevent? As already mentioned, XML bomb should be prevented by default. You may not see it with your payload, as it is not an XML bomb. Use something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack

Comment: i want to prevent xml entity expension fortify issue